# Structured Streaming with multiple Sink's for a single Source

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We are creating a Spark Structured Streaming application where there is a Single Source and Multiple Sink's (Kafka & HDFS). We are on a Spark **`2.3.1`** cluster hence using **`foreachBatch`** on a `DataStreamWriter` is out of our reach. Hence I opted for the multiple Stream Writer approach as being advocated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400950/multiple-writestream-with-spark-streaming) and multiple other places. Unfortunately **only one** of that Stream is working for all batches and the other remains dormant. What am I missing here to solve my problem?

```scala
  val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Spark-Structured-Streaming")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

  val lines = spark.readStream
    .format("socket")
    .option("host", "localhost")
    .option("port", 9999)
    .load()

  val words: Dataset[String] = lines.as[String]
    .flatMap(_.split(" "))
    .map(_.concat(Random.nextInt(10).toString))

  /** THIS DOESN'T STREAM TO HDFS (This work's only when the below one is commented) **/
  words.writeStream
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", "path/to/destination/dir")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "some_location_1")
    .start()

  /** THIS WORK'S **/
  words.writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
    .option("topic", "updates")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "some_location_2")
    .start()

  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

I only see data published to Kafka but I don't see data written to HDFS. Only when I comment out Kafka publishing stream the dormant one come's to life.

UPDATE:
a similar easily reproducible script with simple Sink's

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark-Structured-Streaming").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

    val lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()

    import spark.implicits._

    val words: Dataset[String] = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(_.concat(Random.nextInt(10).toString))

    words.writeStream.queryName("query1").format("console").start()


    words.writeStream.queryName("query2").foreach(new ForeachWriter[String] {
        override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = true

        override def process(value: String): Unit = {
          println(value)
        }

        override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
      })
      .start()

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
  }
```

LOGS: for an input of `A B C`

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/05/30 12:17:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.3.1
20/05/30 12:17:38 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark-Structured-Streaming
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: z001v7w
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: z001v7w
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(z001v7w); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(z001v7w); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/05/30 12:17:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 49262.
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/rr/vxr2k38j6_qcl3xmbf2g_25933gq0_/T/blockmgr-80dcbdff-eb1c-49e5-a33b-47a897735d31
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 127.0.0.1, and started at http://localhost:4040
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 49263.
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on localhost:49263
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 49263, None)
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:49263 with 2004.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 49263, None)
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 49263, None)
20/05/30 12:17:39 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 49263, None)
20/05/30 12:17:40 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/Users/****/spark-warehouse/').
20/05/30 12:17:40 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/****/spark-warehouse/'.
20/05/30 12:17:40 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
20/05/30 12:17:40 WARN TextSocketSourceProvider: The socket source should not be used for production applications! It does not support recovery.
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting query1 [id = a5714e40-553f-4d21-9115-9c0d9ffe950b, runId = 8d206486-36d8-4319-ad3d-fa5cb00a79ca]. Use file:///private/var/folders/rr/vxr2k38j6_qcl3xmbf2g_25933gq0_/T/temporary-5f818bb9-b347-432f-8c43-07fccec0e9e8 to store the query checkpoint.
20/05/30 12:17:43 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got com.tgt.sign.POCTestMain$$anon$1
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "a5714e40-553f-4d21-9115-9c0d9ffe950b",
  "runId" : "8d206486-36d8-4319-ad3d-fa5cb00a79ca",
  "name" : "query1",
  "timestamp" : "2020-05-30T17:17:43.915Z",
  "batchId" : 0,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "getOffset" : 0,
    "triggerExecution" : 10
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "TextSocketSource[host: localhost, port: 9999]",
    "startOffset" : null,
    "endOffset" : null,
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider@5e761dda"
  }
}
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting query2 [id = 776c6082-920a-4406-913f-c1b2eda5f12d, runId = 7d066ebb-fe7b-454c-98c5-2ed05a8c0bda]. Use file:///private/var/folders/rr/vxr2k38j6_qcl3xmbf2g_25933gq0_/T/temporary-7a3485d8-9973-43a7-8a35-4a5dd0745719 to store the query checkpoint.
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
20/05/30 12:17:43 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "776c6082-920a-4406-913f-c1b2eda5f12d",
  "runId" : "7d066ebb-fe7b-454c-98c5-2ed05a8c0bda",
  "name" : "query2",
  "timestamp" : "2020-05-30T17:17:43.991Z",
  "batchId" : 0,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "getOffset" : 0,
    "triggerExecution" : 1
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "TextSocketSource[host: localhost, port: 9999]",
    "startOffset" : null,
    "endOffset" : null,
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "ForeachSink"
  }
}
20/05/30 12:17:49 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Committed offsets for batch 0. Metadata OffsetSeqMetadata(0,1590859069597,Map(spark.sql.shuffle.partitions -> 200, spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass -> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider))
20/05/30 12:17:50 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 474.062005 ms
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 58.908865 ms
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Start processing data source writer: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@6ccc266. The input RDD has 4 partitions.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at POCTestMain.scala:147
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (start at POCTestMain.scala:147) with 4 output partitions
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (start at POCTestMain.scala:147)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at start at POCTestMain.scala:147), which has no missing parents
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 12.0 KB, free 2004.6 MB)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.3 KB, free 2004.6 MB)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:49263 (size: 5.3 KB, free: 2004.6 MB)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1039
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at start at POCTestMain.scala:147) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3))
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 4 tasks
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7851 bytes)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7851 bytes)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7851 bytes)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7995 bytes)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 25.371124 ms
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 12.870672 ms
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 0 is committing.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 2 is committing.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 1 is committing.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 0 committed.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 1 committed.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 2 committed.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 14.157876 ms
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 3 is committing.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DataWritingSparkTask: Writer for partition 3 committed.
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2). 1240 bytes result sent to driver
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 1240 bytes result sent to driver
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1240 bytes result sent to driver
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3). 2297 bytes result sent to driver
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 227 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/4)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 256 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/4)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 233 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/4)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 232 ms on localhost (executor driver) (4/4)
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (start at POCTestMain.scala:147) finished in 0.557 s
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: start at POCTestMain.scala:147, took 0.616436 s
20/05/30 12:17:51 INFO WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWriter@6ccc266 is committing.
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   A8|
|   B9|
|   C4|
+-----+
```

Comment: what exception are you getting ??

Comment: @Srinivas Not getting any Exceptions. Both the Streams are NOT functional, one of them remains dormant through out the session (Kafka Sink is able to publish data, where as HDFS sink remains non functional without any exception)

Comment: Also same is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791975/spark-structured-streaming-multiple-writestreams-to-same-sink

Comment: If possible can you add complete logs ??

Comment: @Srinivas I have added a reproducible script with simple Sink's. And have also added Logs for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understood your problem. You are using `socket` as input source & starting two threads for consuming & writing into sinks.

In `socket (netcat)` once data is consumed from the socket it will not be available, for example

`query1` started first it will read data from socket & write to sink.

`query2` there is no data to read from socket so it will simply sit idle.

In spark document mentioned - `The socket source should not be used for production applications it does not support recovery`

Instead of `socket` try to stream `files` & check if it is working as expected or not.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similiar issue and changed my code to

```
/** THIS DOESN'T STREAM TO HDFS (This work's only when the below one is commented) **/
  val hdfsPush = words.write
    .format("parquet")
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("path", "path/to/destination/dir")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "some_location_1")

  /** THIS WORK'S **/
  val kafkaPush = words.writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
    .option("topic", "updates")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "some_location_2")

kafkaPush.start()
hdfsPush.start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: thanks @QuickSilver!! for some reason your solution didn't work for me. Was there any thing else you did differently apart from what you have mentioned above?

Comment: Both of my out stream were kafka so it worked looks like your one of your outstream is parquet I think you should try `write` instead `writeStream` for parquet with `append` mode